# How foreach works for List of Lists in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl, nested-loops

> ["A","B","C","D","E","F"] - ArrayList 01
>
> [1,2,3,4,5,6] - ArrayList 02
>
> [10,20,30,40,50,60]  - ArrayList 03
>
> [100,200,300,400,500,600] - ArrayList 04
>
> Main_List -
>   [["A","B","C","D","E","F"],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[10,20,30,40,50,60],[100,200,300,400,500,600]];

- Main_List is combination of four Array-lists

**How can I retreive Main_List in to a table which has four columns?**

```
<c:forEach items="${List_parameter}" var="post" varStatus="theCount">
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${post}" var="value" varStatus="cell">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">${theCount.count}</td>
                <td>${value.get(0)}</td>
                <td>${value.get(1)}</td>
                <td>${value.get(2)}</td>
                <td>${value.get(3)}</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

**Servlet passing the list to JSP**

```
Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(Result);
        ControlData controlData = new ControlData();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())  
        {  
            token1 = scanner.nextLine();
            Wtcs = controlData.CtrlWeight(token1);
            NC = controlData.NofConditions(token1);
            Ccspps = controlData.previousComplex(token1);

            cdLine.add(token1);
            wtc.add(Ccspps);
            ncc.add(NC);
            ccpps.add(Wtcs);

        }  

        List arr[]={cdLine,wtc,ncc,ccpps};   
        scanner.close();     //close the scanner  
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/Control_structures.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("Code_string", arr);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: You really want a class for `RowItem` (or whatever the meaning of your parallel lists is).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- If I have a class which has getters and setters then what can I do ?

Comment: EL is friendly like that; you just say `obj.propertyName`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Can't we just extract Main_list data in to that table.?

Comment: You _can_, but parallel arrays (or lists) are a big antipattern and will make your code much more difficult to manage. For example, nobody can tell by looking at your JSP what your cell values are supposed to mean.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I'll update the question with servlet also.. Could you please share your Idea as a Answer. I understand the obj.propertyName thing. But I wold like to know to to do it without a class. I want to know how can I just extract this list into table without a class.. could you please help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209697/discussion-between-jude-and-chrylis-on-strike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.

**In servlet**

```
        Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(Result);
        ControlData controlData = new ControlData();
        List<List<Comparable>> p =new ArrayList<List<Comparable>>();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())  
        {  
            token1 = scanner.nextLine();
            Wtcs = controlData.CtrlWeight(token1);
            NC = controlData.NofConditions(token1);
            Ccspps = controlData.previousComplex(token1);
            List<Comparable> c =new ArrayList<Comparable>();
            c.add(token1);
            c.add(Wtcs);
            c.add(NC);
            c.add(Ccspps);
            p.add(c);
        }  
        scanner.close();     //close the scanner  
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/jsp_page.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("Code_string", p);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Now I have a simple list to pass the JSP.

```
<c:forEach items="${Code_string}" var="post" varStatus="theCount1">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>${post[0]}</td>
                <td>${post[1]}</td>
                <td>${post[2]}</td>
                <td>${post[3]}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Use <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> evaluate EL

2) Create List and add.

3) Set pageContext.setAttribute("list", finalList);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <%
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G");
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
        List<List> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        finalList.add(list1);
        finalList.add(list2);
        pageContext.setAttribute("list", finalList);
    %>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="post" varStatus="theCount">
        <p>List ${theCount.count}</p>
        <c:forEach items="${post}" var="value" varStatus="cell">
            ${value} &nbsp;
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

//Output//

List
List 1

A   B   C   D   E   F   G
List 2

1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Comment: I have already got that Main_list therefore now I want to extract that Main_list data into a table instead of a paragraph. Hope you understand.. any solutions are welcome Rahul :) Thanks for the idea anyway.